# Is it true that $\limsup a_n \geq \limsup b_n$ implies $\limsup a_n^{s_n} \geq \limsup b_n^{s_n}$ for $a_n, b_n \geq 0$ and $s_n > 0$ and increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Potential first step: If $\limsup a_n \geq \limsup b_n$, along some subsequence and for large enough $n_k$ we have $a_{n_k} \geq b_{n_k}$. Then, $a_{n_k}^{s_{n_k}} \geq b_{n_k}^{s_{n_k}}$, so somehow $\limsup a_{n_k}^{s_{n_k}} \geq \limsup b_{n_k}^{s_{n_k}}$?

Comment: You may need to rephrase your question. For example, where comes the $s_n$. The word "increasing" refers to which sequence?

Comment: We may have $a_n<b_n$ for every $n$ and still have $\lim\sup a_n=\lim \sup b_n.$  For example $a_n=1-2^{-n}$ and $b_n=(1+a_n)/2.$

Comment: C_n should have been s_n and that's the increasing sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n = 1-{1 \over n}, b_n = 1+ { 1 \over n}$. Let $s_n = n$.

Then $1 = \lim\sup_n a_n \ge \limsup_n b_n = 1$, but
${1 \over e} = \lim\sup_n a_n^{s_n} < \limsup_n b_n^{s_n} = e$.